# Please let me know how to run test case In IE 9 on windows 7 using selenium grid 1.0.8

Tags: selenium, grid

We are running test cases parallel using selenium grid 1.0.8 in IE 8 on windows XP computer. Each node are configure on different computers. And it is working perfectly.

But when we try to run test case in IE 9 on windows 7 then it is not working. The IE 9 launched but nothing happen.

Please let me know how to run test case In IE 9 on windows 7 using selenium grid 1.0.8

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid 2.0, its recommended

How to run browser in grid using web driver

In grid there is one HUB and multiple Nodes

Here scenario is

Hub-->Mac Machine
Node-->Windows Vista

```
1) Download "Selenium Server"  latest server from " http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ " on    
both machine "Hub" and "Node"

2) Download browser driver in "Node" machine (Download browser driver according to your OS  
either 32-bit or 64-bit)
```

3) Open terminal in Hub machine and type

```
java -jar "selenium server location" -role hub <Enter>

open browser and type "http://localhost:4444/grid/console"
```

4) Open terminal in Node machine and type

```
java -jar "selenium server location" -role node -port 5566 -hub http://Hub ip address:4444/grid  
/register -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=<path of ie web driver, downloaded in step 2>  <Enter>

-Dwebdriver.ie.driver --> to specify the browser driver path
```

5) this code should be use to driver browser

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilies = DesiredCapabilities.internetexplorer();
capabilies.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("<node url>:<port>/wd/hub"), capabilies);
```